# It's posible to do SpeechToText(Speech recognition) and afterwards TextToSpeech (using same text and same voice)?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-to-text

I'm working on a program for tone deaf people. I've working with sapi and a TTs. The program does a 3D animation with a hand at the same time. But the problem is that the voices (also when a put them at its slowest speech) is to fast for what I want. So, I've thought on speech recognition, but the problem is that I've to do a large process to the text before the animation start.

So, I want to know if It would be posible to do speech recognition(from my voice on a .wave file) and afterwards do the same process of TTs (with Sapi events...) but using the .wave with my voice.

If It's posible, please tell me how. If you think there are better alternatives, let my see them.

Thanks for your time (and excuse my English)

Jesuskiewicz

Comment: Are you sure that you can't just synchronize the animations to the viseme or phoneme events?  Also, why not process the text before sending the text to the TTS engine?

Comment: No, because, even when a configure the TTS to speak with the slowest speed, is too fast, and also it makes the voice sound on a robotic way.In addition the animations are referenced at sylabe level, so I can't synchronize it in real time.

Comment: so, if I'm understanding the problem correctly, you have some text, and you want to use TTS, but you also need to synchronize the TTS with the signing animation.

The problem you're having is that the signing animations are relatively long, and you're losing synchronization.

What I'm not (yet) understanding is what you want to have happen when the animations are too long - do you want to insert pauses between the words?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to speak a text(with a microphone), and recognize that text at the same time that that voice is registered on a wav file. Then, use the wave file and sing the animations with the voice of that wave file. So I only want to synchronize the voice from the wav with the animations. Why to do that way, because a need to do an analysis of the text, in order to load the correct animation (the information of visemes and phonemes aren't enought

Comment: I still dont understand why you need to recognize the wave file.  There's no inherent synchronization between the recognition engine and the tts engine (or, for that matter, any particular synchronization between the recognition engine and real time).  So, why don't you just analyze the text, generate the animations, and *then* send it to the TTS engine, synchronizing to phonemes/visemes as appropriate?

Comment: "why don't you just analyze the text, generate the animations, and then send it to the TTS engine, synchronizing to phonemes/visemes as appropriate?" That's what I've done until now. But the TTS is too fast, and the voice is too robotic if I use that slower. So, I don't want to use the TTS. I want to use my voice, recognize and store it (on a wav) , and then load the wav and synchronize phonemes/visemes with it.

Comment: Oh, *now* I get it.  You want to use *your* voice as the output, and generate phoneme markup on the recorded audio.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you want to happen, I can say that as far as I know, the SAPI SR engine doesn't really provide phoneme-level markup that's synchronized to the incoming text.

What you could *try* (although I have no real expectation for this to work) would be to take the audio, run it through a pronunciation grammar to generate phonemes, and then take the text elements to find the corresponding bits of audio.

When I say a 'pronunciation grammar', I mean a dictation grammar with the pronunciation model loaded - set it up like this:

```
CComPtr<ISpRecoGrammar> cpGrammar;
... initialize SR engine and create a grammar ...
cpGrammar->LoadDictation(L"Pronunciation", SPLO_STATIC);
```

In your recognition handler, you would need to parse out the elements:

```
ISpRecoResult* ipReco;
SPPHRASE* pPhrase;
ipReco->GetPhrase(&pPhrase);
for (int i = 0; i < pPhrase->Rule.ulCountOfElements; ++i)
{
    const SPPHRASEELEMENT * pElem = pPhrase->pElements + i;
    // examine pElem->ulAudioSizeTime, etc.
}
::CoTaskMemFree(pPhrase);
```

I hope this is enough to get you started...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I gonna take another way (If I find it)... My error was I thought that when you do the recognition, there were Viseme_events just like there are when you do Synthesis... But It's true, I have realized that It didn't make sense, recognition is at word level. 

Thanks again